# how to render a file and send data to page in the same GET request

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ejs

I am using angularjs on client-side and experss.js in server-side , i want to render a page and send data to the page (to fill a table) in the same get request

i tried using ejs engine to fill the table in the server-side and then render the page , but the problem with this solution is that the client-side (angularjs) cant access or manipulate the data.
other solution is (atrivial one) is to

1. make get request to get the page on cient-side
2. render the page on server-side
3. make another get request from client-side to get the data
4. send the data  from server to client

The problem with this is that it contains two get requests. 
Is there a possible way to render the page and send the data in one get request?

I am doing this to make the loading on site more efficient. Can i acheive more efficiency with one GET request ?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. You can only have a single response to a given request. The browser is either expecting an HTML document or it is expecting JSON, it doesn't make sense to give it both at once. but you could render the page and send the data at the same time:

```
res.render('reports',{data:json});
```

and then access those data in the newly rendered page.

alternatively you could send a flag when making the call , and then decide whether you want to render or send based on this flag.

Or Ideally, it needs to be 2 separate route, one spitting json and other rendering a view. Else, you could pass a url param, depending on which you return json or render a view.

```
router.get('/reports/json', function(req,res){
   var data = JSON_OBJECT;
   res.send(data);
});

router.get('/reports', function(req,res){
   var data = JSON_OBJECT;
   res.render('path-to-view-file', data);
});
```

Comment: that was my first solution , i did not think about the flag that was nice , but the problem i faced with this solution is that i cant access the data in angularjs , and that affects other features on the website , I consulted an expert with this question he said that I will not gain much effiecincy with one get request , and it is  best practice to seperate the requests. thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

To access data in an AngularJS app without a second server request, include a `.value` script:

```
<script>
    angular.module("myApp").value("myData",
         <JSON data here>
    }
</script>
```

Then in the controller, inject it:

```
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope, myData) {
    $scope.data = myData;
})
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS angular.module API Reference - `.value` method](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#value)

Answer (score -1):

Could you please try using rout.getparam and pass values in route in the get request